# Optional dynamic route without a custom server - NextJS - 9.5.2

Tags: javascript, next.js

I am trying to create localized routes with optional first param like `/lang?/../../`, but without a custom server.
From 9.5 NextJS has this option dynamic optionall parameters, if you set the folder or a file with a name:
`[[...param]]`. I did that.
The problem is that, i have other routes and I want all of them to be with that lang prefix, ut optional with default language, if that lang is  not provided

I have a folder `[[...lang]]` with a file index.js, with simple function component just for testing. Now optional parameter works for the home page `/` and `/en`, but I have other files, which I want to be with that optional lang. For the example, I have `about.js` and I want to access it via `/en/about` and `/about`.

I can't put `about.js` inside `[[...lang]]`, because, I am getting an error:

> Failed to reload dynamic routes: Error: Catch-all must be the last part of the URL.

I know what it says and why is that, but I have a fixed collection of languages `['en', 'fr']` and I can check is there a lang.

Is there a way, without a custom server to use optionally a dynamic first part of the path, like

`/en/about` and `/about` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are talking about this feature. Have a look on this https://nextjs.org/blog/next-9-5#support-for-rewrites-redirects-and-headers

Comment: Yes, I have found that, but thanks, it works with `rewrites`.

Answer (score 0):

To extend the answer from @Vibhav, in `next.config.js`:

```
const nextConfig = {

    async rewrites(){
        return [
// URLs without a base route lang param like /my-page
            {
                source: '/',
                destination: '/'
            },
// URLs with a base route lang param like /en/my-page

            {
                source: '/:lang*/:page*',
                destination: '/:page*'
            },
// URLs `/en/post/post_id`
            {
                source: '/:lang/:path/:page',
                destination: '/:path/:page'
            },
        ]
    }
};

module.exports = withBundleAnalyzer(nextConfig);
```

- all pages are in the `pages` folder. Not the best solution for now, because it works in a deep up to like `/pages/another-folder/file`.

You can even get the lang param in your pages or `_app.js`:

```
....
const router = useRouter();

if(router.query.lang){
    pageProps.lang = router.query.lang;
}
console.log(pageProps.lang);

return (
    <Layout>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Layout>
)
```

For URL - /en/my-page, `router.query.lang` will be equal to `en`.
For URL - /my-page,  `router.query.lang` will be `undefined`, but you can set a default lang.